# How to change the hostname for the SQL server?

Tags: sql-server

I moved a system 'asp.net' to another server and now I need to change the hostname for the SQL server, but the `<connectionStrings/>`(web.config) is empty, where should I change?

Comment: Have you looked in the `<appSettings>` collection? Prior to asp.net 2.0 this was the recommended place to store connection string.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be somewhere or it would never have worked.  You can grep/search for the connection string in your code, or you didn't actually move the config file.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change connection strings whereever they are present.

They might have been added in the `appSettings` section, or for state using SQL Server in the `sessionState` section.

It is possible that the connection strings have been put into a config file of their own - does the `connectionStrings` section have a `configSource` attribute? If so, that's where they would be found.

It is easy enough to search for `Initial Catalog=` or `Server=` within your config files.

Comment: i found web.dll,Library.dll,web.pdb,Liberary.pdb. maybe the connection string could be inside them?

Comment: @Kokdui2 - it's possible. It _shouldn't_ be, but it might be.

Comment: @Kokdui2 - You need the source code of these files. You can use a disassembler such as Reflector to try and see what is in them, but this will not let you change the code.

Comment: where can i download disassembler?

Comment: @Kokdui2 - Google `Reflector`.

Comment: idk why but i can't open Reflector, it's crashing when i tried to open

Comment: @Kokdui2 - That, I can't help you with.

Comment: look the error that i'm getting when tried to run the asp.net system:

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: @Kokdui2 - Very strange reflector you got there. It shouldn't be using a SQL Server.

Comment: i found the connectionstring inside the library.dll, look:

[DefaultSettingValue("Data Source= ~

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the code, then fire up notepad++ like editor and find the sqlconnection object.. there you will have the connection string or reading mechanism employed.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do the following for a quick fix.

Modify the [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) to point the old server name to the new IP address.  This should work, unless the connection string has an IP address in it.

Also, you should check with other software to make sure the new database server is running properly.  Just to be sure it's the application having the problem, and not the server.